# Spark Scala Schema for type Unit is not supported

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am a new learner for Spark Scala.

I have a udf and it run failed return 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Unit is not supported

Code:

```
  val stay_dates = udf( (ci: Date, co: Date) => {
    val miliseconds_per_day = 24*60*60*1000
    println(miliseconds_per_day + " miliseconds_per_day!!!")
    val nDays = ( co.getTime() - ci.getTime() ) / miliseconds_per_day
    (0L until nDays).map(i => new Date(ci.getTime() + i * miliseconds_per_day) )
    println(nDays + " nDays!!!")
  }
  )
```

Comment: but you are not returning a data your printing and println returns type Unit

Comment: Thanks @eliasah, we can remove the 2 rows start from println... But this udf still return error like the subject mentioned